# XP - Context Menu - Move Selected Files to a Specific Folder

Tags: file, windows-xp, contextmenu, directory, move

G'day all and thanks for your help. Every now and then I have to copy downloaded files (after changing them) to a specific folder. In this example lets say d:\myfolder. I want to be able to do this quick with no hassles.

It was suggested that I look at the registry and the windows context menu. Truth be told I have no idea what to do.

Simply put; How do I MOVE files I selected to d:\myfolder from the context menu?

If possible greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

PS: The closest I could find was:

http://thismatter.com/tutorials/software/windows-xp/copy-move-files-more-efficiently.htm

This is almost there but cannot specify a specific folder.

Answer (score 1):

Oof, a bit late in finding this question and responding, but here goes...

I want to do the same thing you're requesting, with the same aim: to do so in as few steps as possible.

The simplest solution for you would be to just create a shortcut for the target folder to which you wish to direct your files, and then move that shortcut into your "Send To" folder.

One add'l tip on this approach: selecting the target folder shortcut in the "Send To" menu will copy your file to the selected location; however, selecting the folder when also holding down the SHIFT key will move the file to that folder, instead.